# Why does the hash method return a different value in rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

In my app

```
<%= "a_string".hash %>
```

renders as 4318227885144361583

in rails console:

```
$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.3)
1.9.2p290 :001 > "a_string".hash 
 => -917414088101530508
```

Same machine, same rails app, same environment, same version of ruby.

Why does it get different values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby 1.9 has always had this behaviour: part of the information that goes into the hashing algorithm is randomly picked on a per process basis

Versions of ruby 1.8.7 up to p352 behaved the way you expected: the hash of a string depended only on the contents of the string.

Unfortunately this opened the door for a type of denial of service attack: you could choose a large number of parameters that all hashed to the same value and would as such invoke pathological behaviour in the ruby Hash class: instead of O(1) access times you'd get O(n). This was fixed in ruby 1.8.7p357. There are more details in [this post](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-talk/391607) to the ruby talk list.

Comment: Thanks, makes perfect sense once you know!

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with Rails.

Fire up IRB again and see what you get across sessions:

```
1.8.7 :003 > "a_string".hash
 => -1300030395 
1.8.7 :004 > exit
$ irb
1.8.7 :001 > "a_string".hash
 => 1520614759 
1.8.7 :002 > exit
$ irb
1.8.7 :001 > "a_string".hash
 => 1991940479
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-hash

I would offer up, that most likely you want to do something like this?

```
require 'digest/md5' 
Digest::MD5.hexdigest("a_string")
 => "7a0d3f5c88466513b32cee16e0620162"
```

That will always return the same result.